# Docker not catching env vars

Tags: java, docker-compose, shared-libraries

I'm trying to run 3 containers through docker-compose, with postgres, cassandra and my webapp, which has a embedded tomcat server with some dependencies as ARP/Native. This libraries are located in a folder called "lib" at jar's same level.

I'm running a PoC on Windows 10 (using Linux containers) before moving it to a CentOS server, if it works on the PoC. I searched over the net and seems like is not an isolated problem but or I have no find the solution, or the solution showed didn't work for me. Here is my docker-compose.yml, with all the related files/folders stored at same level:

```
version: '3.1' 

services:
fulmar-webapp:
    container_name: "my-webapp"
    image: openjdk:11-jre-slim
    hostname: mywebapp
    volumes:
        - ./lib:/home/lib
        - ./fulmar-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:/home/mywebapp-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar
        
    entrypoint:
        - java
        - -jar
        - /home/mywebapp-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar
    
    environment:
        - LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/lib
       
        - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/mydb
        - spring.datasource.username=postgres
        - spring.datasource.password=postgres
        - spring.jpa.hibernate.ddlAuto=update
        
    network_mode: bridge    
    ports:
        - 8443:8443
        - 8080:8080
    links:
        - postgresql 
        - cassandra     
     
postgresql:
 
    container_name: "mydb"
    image: postgres:11.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: mydb
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
       - ./startup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/startup.sql 
       - postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      
    ports:
        - 5432:5432
    network_mode: bridge
    

cassandra:
    container_name: "cassandra"
    image: cassandra
    ports:
        - 9042:9042
    network_mode: bridge
```

volumes:
postgresdata:

Not sure if is not properly mapping the folder with the libraries, or is not actually mounting the volume. This is exactly the Environment var I need to put in there:
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/libraries/lib

Two results I have encountered:

1-Tomcat exception cause it can not find the libraries:

```
[ERROR][org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase#log(175)] Failed to 
initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol- 
8080]] | org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: The configured protocol 
[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] requires the APR/native library 
which is not available
```

2-WARNING: The LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.

Thanks you all in advance

EDIT: just let you know the once I run docker-compose up, and my app throws this exception, the container is no longer available so I'm unable to run any commands in it

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong syntax, it should be like this:

```
environment:
    - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/lib
```

Comment: Just tried it, still getting same exception:
[14/06/2019 10:53:10][ERROR][org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase#log(175)] Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol-8080]]
    | org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: The configured protocol [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] requires the APR/native library which is not available